# Spring Batch creating multiple files .Gradle based project

Tags: java, spring-batch

I need to create 3 separate files.

My Batch job should read from Mongo then parse through the information and find the "business" column (3 types of business: RETAIL,HPP,SAX) then create a file for their respective business. the file should create either RETAIL +formattedDate; HPP + formattedDate; SAX +formattedDate as the file name and the information found in the DB inside a txt file. Also, I need to set the .resource(new FileSystemResource("C:\filewriter\index.txt)) into something that will send the information to the right location, right now hard coding works but only creates one .txt file.

example:

```
 @Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<PaymentAudit> writer() {
    LOG.debug("Mongo-writer");      
    FlatFileItemWriter<PaymentAudit> flatFile = new 
    FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<PaymentAudit>()
            .name("flatFileItemWriter")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource("C:\\filewriter\\index.txt)) 
         //trying to create a path instead of hard coding it
            .lineAggregator(createPaymentPortalLineAggregator())
            .build();
    String exportFileHeader = 
   "CREATE_DTTM";
    StringHeaderWriter headerWriter = new 
    StringHeaderWriter(exportFileHeader);
    flatFile.setHeaderCallback(headerWriter);
    return flatFile;

}
```

My idea would be something like but not sure where to go:

```
public Map<String, List<PaymentAudit>> getPaymentPortalRecords() {
List<PaymentAudit> recentlyCreated = 
PaymentPortalRepository.findByCreateDttmBetween(yesterdayMidnight,
        yesterdayEndOfDay);

List<PaymentAudit> retailList = new ArrayList<>();
List<PaymentAudit> saxList = new ArrayList<>();
List<PaymentAudit> hppList = new ArrayList<>();
//String exportFilePath = "C://filewriter/";??????
recentlyCreated.parallelStream().forEach(paymentAudit -> {
    if (paymentAudit.getBusiness().equalsIgnoreCase(RETAIL)) {
        retailList.add(paymentAudit);
    } else if 
(paymentAudit.getBusiness().equalsIgnoreCase(SAX)) {
        saxList.add(paymentAudit);
    } else if 
(paymentAudit.getBusiness().equalsIgnoreCase(HPP)) {
        hppList.add(paymentAudit);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a file for each business object type, you can use the [`ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html). In your case, you can create a writer for each type and add them as delegates in the composite item writer.

As per creating the filename dynamically, you need to use a step scoped writer. There is an example in the [Step Scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding) section of the reference documentation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I use the 'ClassifierCompositeItemWriter' in conjunction with my 'flatfileitemWriter'? or do i Change the flat file writer to the classifer?

Comment: you create 3 writers of type `FlatFileItemWriter` and set them as delegates in the composite writer. Then you use the composite writer in the step. Here is an example with two writers: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriterTests.java#L44. You just need to adapt the classifier to classify items according to your 3 business types.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to create the 3 files. I need help with one more thing. Lets say I need to find everything that comes from a column in the Mongodb called item1 and send it to the item1 text file, how do i just get those that are a part of item1 but not from item2 which item2 should go to the item2 text file.. and so on,. s there a conditional statement that should go in the flatfilitemwriter?